# Why windows.open() is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, window-object

I have created url object with Blob and it's type is 'application/pdf'

> ```
> const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
> setUrl(URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)); // mediaSource is a Blob
> ```

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
> if (url) window.open(url, '_blank')
> [url]);
> ```

By this useEffect(), url is opening in another tab but pdf occupying less space and added scroll bars to it

[image: Partially loading image]

If I copy and paste same url in another chrome tab it is working as expected
[image: Expected image]

I tried these, but nothing work. Please help !

> ```
> window.open(url, '_blank', "height=500");
> window.open(url, '_blank', "fullscreen=yes");
> ```

Comment: Could you try `useEffect(() => {
  if (url) {
    const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.onload = () => {
      win.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    };
  }
}, [url]);`